# Cant run some shopify commands due to an error about ruby version incompatibility

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, shopify, shopify-app

I am new to shopify CLI and trying to run `shopify theme pull` or `shopify theme serve` but cannot due to an error I keep on running into

```
PS C:\Users\Russell\shopify\shopifyApp\starter> shopify theme serve
Your environment Ruby version, 3.1.1, is outside of the range supported by the CLI, 2.6.6..<3.1.0, and might cause incompatibility issues.
X An unexpected error occured.
        To submit an issue include the stack trace.
        To print the stack trace, add the environment variable SHOPIFY_CLI_STACKTRACE=1.
```

ive tried to downgrage ruby to 3.1.1 using `gem update --system 3.1.1` but get this in my cmd

```
C:\Users\Russell>gem update --system 3.1.1
ERROR:  rubygems 3.1.1 is not supported on 3.1.1. The oldest version supported by this ruby is 3.3.3
```

im using windows 10 and ruby 3.3.3

Comment: Are you able to solve the above issue?

Answer (score -1):

Well I  managed to get a solution and what I did was :
This happens because when you create a Development store, it won't properly link your Shopify Partners account to the new created store.

A partial solution was mentioned here #1309 (comment)

This is what I do to solve the problem on my side:

1.- Logout from the Development store admin dashboard
2.- Login again by visiting the direct URL. Example: https://[store-name].myshopify.com/admin

Here use your Shopify Partners account (the one that you used to create the development store). Don't worry if you see an error message or if you have to login again. Ideally you should see the admin dashboard again.

4.- Login to your Shopify account (not Partners). Go to: https://shopify.com/login

At this point you should see the new Development store listed. This means it is now linked to your account.

Go back to the CLI and try again. You may have to do `shopify whoami and/or shopify logout shopify login`
[github solution to the problem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/issues/1361#issuecomment-879426041)